# iMacros to get TITLE and URL from searches Google (SERP)

Tags: imacros

I cannot get the URL from search result Google, and only need to get main URL no need full URL. please help.

sample SERP:
googleforeducation.blogspot.com/.../teach-and-learn-from-everywh

WANT to become:
googleforeducation.blogspot.com

I did try and below is the full script. Thank you.

```
VERSION BUILD=8871104 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
SET !REPLAYSPEED FAST
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
URL GOTO=https://www.google.co.id/search?q=%2Bblogspot.com&bav=on.2,or.&biw=1064&bih=666&dpr=1#tbs=qdr:m&q=learn+blogspot+site:blogspot.com

TAG POS={{!LOOP}} TYPE=H3 ATTR=TXT:* EXTRACT=TXT
TAG POS={{!LOOP}} TYPE=CITE ATTR=CLASS:_Rm EXTRACT=HREF
SET !EXTRACT EVAL("want to get only <something>.blogspot.com OR only main URL");

SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=* FILE=Google.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SET !EXTRACT EVAL("'{{!EXTRACT}}'.split('/')[0];")
```

Comment: that macro still not getting URL, but EANF even play loop 10 times.
how to get the URL from Google search page?

Comment: (1) See 'Related' questions on the right. (2) Try to search on 'stackoverflow'. There have been already similar questions several times. (3) I answered the part as to "WANT to become: googleforeducation.blogspot.com" .

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".

Comment: Shugar, your iMacros skills are unbeatable but unfortunately his issue is that he is looking for a simple HREF tag in a very complicated HTML layout. You did fill in the missing code but the first part he suggested does not even catch the URL. I suggested using regex to look for URLs. Please review my code, your input means a lot to me. thanks

Comment: oke like this... When Google show this (open please) https://www.google.co.id/#hl=en&q=what+is+marketing+site:blogspot.com <-- then what i want? i need only TITLE as TXT (element H3) and the TEXT show in green text indicates URLs (element TYPE=CITE ATTR=CLASS:_Rm). The URLs need only main URL means unti .com from the page Google result, not like this enotesmba.blogspot.com › ... › MBA Notes OR NOT LIKE THIS kalyan-city.blogspot.com/.../what-is-market-types-and-classification.html

Answer (score 1):

**Your Question: Run search in google for param in site and gather sundomains from results.**
-***Jump to last code sample for a working solution***-

1)My suggestion is to look for the solution in another technology and not in macros. E.g Perl + LWP to get page source and then regex to pars it.

2)To the point, Your macro does not work because the element you selected does not contain an HREF tag, please use "Inspect Element" button in your browser to see you page layout.
I would use REGEX with iMacros to locate urls at pre-defined locations, for example the TRANSLATE button that always appears next to the finding in a foreign domain. (Or webchache, see last example).
**The next code catches the subdomain for the first translate button only.**

```
SEARCH SOURCE=REGEXP:"https://translate.google.{20,50}u=http://(.{1,50}).blogspot.com/&" EXTRACT="Subdomain is $1"
PROMPT {{!EXTRACT}}
```

Unfortunately when trying to loop the regex the grouping keeps overwriting $1
E.G **(Not working properly but this is the more elegant way to go if someone can fix it)**:

```
SEARCH SOURCE=REGEXP:"(?:https://translate.google.{20,50}u=http://(.{1,50}).blogspot.com/&.+?){1,6}" EXTRACT="Subdomains are $1 $2 $3 $4 $5 $6"
PROMPT {{!EXTRACT}}
```

**?:** is to disable extracting for current grouping. 
**{1,6}** is to run 1 to 6 times and extract the subdomain.

A Walkaround could be to copy past the code 6?8?20? times. **This time i'm going to use a different anchor (webcache link) that should work for more people out of the box regardless of language.**
E.G:

```
URL GOTO=https://www.google.co.il/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=tHCOV5S_INHb8Afd24GwCg#tbs=qdr:m&q=learn+blogspot+site:blogspot.com
SEARCH SOURCE=REGEXP:"(?:webcache.{19}com/search.q=cache:.{12}:(.{1,40}.blogspot.com)/).+?(?:webcache.{19}com/search.q=cache:.{12}:(.{1,40}.blogspot.com)/).+?(?:webcache.{19}com/search.q=cache:.{12}:(.{1,40}.blogspot.com)/).+?(?:webcache.{19}com/search.q=cache:.{12}:(.{1,40}.blogspot.com)/).+?(?:webcache.{19}com/search.q=cache:.{12}:(.{1,40}.blogspot.com)/).+?(?:webcache.{19}com/search.q=cache:.{12}:(.{1,40}.blogspot.com)/).+?(?:webcache.{19}com/search.q=cache:.{12}:(.{1,40}.blogspot.com)/).+?(?:webcache.{19}com/search.q=cache:.{12}:(.{1,40}.blogspot.com)/).+?" EXTRACT="Domains are $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8"
PROMPT {{!EXTRACT}}
```

**Last one is a working solution for you**, but code-wise it is ugly.
If someone reads this at a later time when google changed the page layout you will need to "Inspect element" on the page, search for "cache" and tweak the regex a little  bit. 
If you want more explanation for the regex i'd be glad to help step by step

Comment: I'm curious what the asker will tell about your expanded explanation... Believe that my comment & answer are quite enough.

Comment: Trying to slowly build up my reputation with hard work, long explanations and hours or researching solutions for other people. Really annoying that they don't even bother upvoting or marking correct answer.

Comment: I don't care of that so much, just trying to help a little.